Dirac operator on $\operatorname{Spin}(7)$, $G_2$ and $\operatorname{SU}(3)$ manifolds
$\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$Let's take a $\Spin(7)$ manifold $M$ (the $\Spin(7)$ structure can have torsion), then the standard Dirac operator from negavtive spinors to positive spinors can be seen as (up to some constants)
\begin{align*}
\Omega^3_8\xrightarrow{\pi_{1\oplus 7}\circ d}\Omega^4_1\oplus\Omega^4_7.
\end{align*}
On a $G_2$ manifold this becomes
\begin{align*}
\Omega^3_7\oplus\Omega^3_1\xrightarrow{\pi_{1\oplus 7}\circ d}\Omega^4_1\oplus\Omega^4_7.
\end{align*}
I want to know what happens to the $\SU(3)$ case synonymously (notice I am working with real spinors, so I don't want the $\sqrt{2}(\bar\partial+\bar\partial^*)$ description).
My guess is something along the lines
\begin{align*}
\Omega^3_6\oplus\Omega^3_\text{Re}\oplus\Omega^3_\text{Im}\xrightarrow{\pi_{1\oplus 1\oplus 6}\circ d}\Omega^4_1\oplus\Omega^4_1\oplus\Omega^4_6.
\end{align*}
Say $(X,\Omega,\omega)$ is an $\SU(3)$ manifold. Then,
\begin{align*}
\Omega^3_6=\{\alpha\wedge\omega:\alpha\in\Omega^1\}\\
\Omega^3_\text{Re}=\operatorname{Span} (\operatorname{Re}\Omega)\\
\Omega^3_\text{Im}=\operatorname{Span} (\operatorname{Im}\Omega)\\
\Omega^4_6=\{\alpha\wedge\operatorname{Re}\Omega:\alpha\in\Omega^1\}\\
\Omega^4_1=\operatorname{Span}(\omega^2).
\end{align*}
I am confused if this is correct and then what is the other $1$-dimensional part on the right hand side? Notice this is the full spinor bundle on $X$ since it has real dimension $8$.
